# Can't display date from server in ui-grid columnDef header with angularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-ui-grid

I started working with ui-grid version 3 a couple of weeks ago and was able to successfully bring firebase data objects in my grid. 
Now, I'd like to display the date from the server every time a form entry is submitted, even though the date field is not a field in the form, I will need to show it on the grid to have a date reference for every successful submission.

In my controller I've changed code to better reflect question:

var timeRef = new Firebase('https://xxc16.firebaseio.com/calls');

```
timeRef.set('time')
.set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
.on("value", function(snapshot){
     var currentServerTime = snapshot.val();
     console.log('The server time set for this call is:'+currentServerTime);
});

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {name:'Created On', field: 'createdOn', width:120,cellTemplate:"<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'> {{3+3}} -{{grid.appScope.createdOn | date:'MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss a'}}</div>"},
        {name:'firstname', field: 'firstname'},
        {name:'lastname', field: 'lastname'},...
```

I have:

- firebase.js 2.3.1

  - angularfire.min.js 1.1.3

[image]

data structure:

[image]

Comment: In your cellTemplate I see you are getting the createdOn as function `row.entity.createdOn()`. It should refer to your field like `row.entity.createdOn`

Comment: I meant to type createdOn as an scope variable. I don't see nothing on the view {{createdOn}}, as well. Is this the right way to get the date when a form entry is submitted? because in my postCall() func I have an scope variable called date and I tried it to set it on the columnDef but no date is displayed.

Comment: That should be Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. It's hard to help you troubleshoot if the code does not accurately reflect your use case. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Update: added code to improve question. Let me know if I'm in the right path. What I'm trying to do is add a child node to the calls parent node so I can retrieve the timestamp every time a user make a new form entry. But I get: TypeError: cannot read property 'on' of undefined. It does create a child but outside of the calls node. How do I create a the 'time' child inside the dynamic subtree node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a value to a cell template in ui-grid, its better to go with `appScopeProviver`.

You can define the `appScopeProvider` in your ui-grid configuration object as follows,

`appScopeProvider: {}`

now any value exposed on appScopeProvider can be accessed inside the templates using `grid.appScope.yourVariableName`

So in your case, you need to expose your value on appScopeProvider as follows,

```
appScopeProvider {
  createdOn: $scope.createdOn
 }
```

Now you can access the same in your template as follows,

```
cellTemplate:"<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'>{{grid.appScope.createdOn | date:'MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss a'}}</div>"
```

Your value will be bound to your template.

However, if your values will change per row, instead of property you can define a function which can return the date.

For e.g

```
appScopeProvider: {
  getCreatedOn: function() {
     // your logic here to get the created on date.
     // return your value.
  }
}
```

Below I have provided a sample snippet where I am creating new column (created date) and binding my value present on `$scope.createdOn` defined in controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ui.grid"]);

app.controller("uiGridCntrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", city: "Washington"},
                  {name: "Tiancum", city: "NY"},
                  {name: "Jacob", city: "LA"}];
  
  
  $scope.createdOn = new Date();
  
  $scope.gridData = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
      {field: 'city', displayName: 'City'},
      {field: 'Created On', displayName: 'Created Date', cellTemplate:"<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'>{{grid.appScope.createdOn | date:'MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss a'}}</div>"}
    ],
    
    appScopeProvider: {
      'createdOn': $scope.createdOn
    }
       
  }
                   
                   
}]);
```

```css
.ui-grid-style {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="uiGridCntrl">
  <div class="ui-grid-style" ui-grid="gridData"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hey Amit, it did worked with the current date method, however I get {".sv":"timestamp"} when Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is set to createdOn variable. Since this date value is not coming with the form data, I will need to provide it as the dynamic date that the firebase server generates. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serg_23/82n8523n/26/).

Comment: Hi @serg The fiddle you provided is not working for me. However, I do not understand the issue you are facing. I have already explained how we can bind data to template. I have never worked with firebase but if you are getting date value from firebase server and is successfully bound to scope variable, then the method I explained will surely work for you.

Comment: Got advanced in my project, unblocked. Understood more of the JS code because your detailed answer, that's what matter as helping others.

Comment: @serg Glad I could be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a placeholder that is used at the server to generate a server-based timestamp. It is not a JavaScript Date object. Thus, you cannot use it as a Date object. A read of the [API docs for TIMESTAMP](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html) should make this clear.

Locally, you should simply use new Date() or Date.now().

```
$scope.calldate = new Date();
```

If you really want to confuse your users by showing them the server time instead of their local time, check out .info/serverTimeOffset in [offline capabilities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency). (hint: you don't want to do that)

Note that when setting the timestamp on data that is saved to the server, using Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is very appropriate.

Also see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/syuzw9k1/) for an example of manipulating date epochs into local Date objects.

Comment: Yes, I saw the api docs when doing research but I'm still struggling with the syntax, I understood Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP can generate a valid date for the object in question. Instead I get {".sv":"timestamp"} in every row. I'm reading this [doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html), but where do you get this serverTimeOffset for this Fb url ref? => https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/serverTimeOffset

Comment: Was to read docs in more detail and improve code a bit. Now I get the TypeError message in console. But in the database I see a time entry(in the wrong place) with the timestamp value. Why do I get the error => cannot read property 'on' of undefined?